# How to XML configure Spring bean for constructor injection when bean has empty varargs constructor

Tags: java, xml, spring, variadic-functions

I have the following class definition:

```
package sample;

public class Foo {
    private String[] args;

    public Foo(String... args) {
        this.args = args;
    }
}
```

so I can create instances of this class without any argument (leave empty varargs):

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

but analogical XML bean configuration:

```
<bean id="test" class="sample.Foo"/>
```

gives me compile-time error:

```
No matching constructor found in class 'Foo'
```

I found the way to get rid of that, but it's quite long:

```
<bean id="test" class="sample.Foo">
    <constructor-arg name="args">
        <list/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Is there a way to write this definition in a simpler way? 
Why do I have to pass as an argument the whole list?

Comment: I guess this question is only about the Spring XML config and adding an explicit default constructor to your Foo class won't answer it?

Comment: It would be workaround rather than solving my problem. I'm currently training Spring xml configuration and I wanted to know, if there are other, simpler ways to pass empty argument list as varargs.